# Why is Cordova unable to add notes to existing Android Contact?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova to update the notes of an existing contact in Android using the following code.

```
    if(new_contacts[index].note == null)
       new_contacts[index].note = '';

    new_contacts[index].note += notes;

    new_contacts[index].save(onSuccess,onError);
```

For some unknown reason, the notes never get added if it was already empty. But if the notes had some content already, then the value from my variable gets appended successfully.

I have used the Cordova-Plugin-Contacts to deal with the native contacts. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts

This very same code is working appropriately for iOS 10 and iOS 11
The note field is a DOMString and I'm unable to crack this down. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the reason behind this, but Cloning the contact which is being edited and then saving the cloned contact solved the problem for me.